# GetOpenFileNameW Function Doesn't Seem To Be Working Properly Anymore

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10

I'm having a problem in Windows 10 with the Win32 API using the Comdlg32.lib library.

It seems like the functionality for the GetOpenFileNameW function listed here:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamew/)

Is opening a file browsing window briefly, then crashing the program.

This functionality used to be working fine on Windows 10, but now it appears to be broken.

My current update version of Windows 10 is the following:
Microsoft Windows
Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.2604)

For the following short piece of Windows CPP code that uses the Comdlg32.lib library:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main() {
    wchar_t Filename[500];
    OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize  = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner    = NULL; 
    ofn.lpstrFile    = Filename;
    ofn.nMaxFile     = (unsigned int)1000000;
    ofn.lpstrTitle   = L"Select a File";
    ofn.Flags        = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_EXPLORER;
    if (GetOpenFileNameW( &ofn )) {
    }
}
```

The expected behavior is that it will open up a file browser window, allow the user to browse for a file, then do nothing after that.

However, while the above code previously had that behavior, it seems recently the behavior has changed. It will instead open the file browser window for a second, then the file browser window will freeze, then the program will crash.

I'm currently trying to run this program on Windows 10, and it is exhibiting this behavior. I had run it previously on Windows 10 and it was not exhibiting this behavior, so I'm wondering if some update to Windows 10 deprecated the GetOpenFileNameW functionality or deprecated this particular way of doing it.

I guess my question is this. Is the above code correct? Is it missing something important that might cause a Windows window to crash?

If the above code is correct, does that mean this functionality just no longer works in Windows 10? Has it been deprecated?

Comment: Why are you telling Windows your buffer is a million characters in size when it's only 500?

Comment: always check the returns

Comment: @pm100 what returns if the program is crashing from within the function?

Comment: @pm100 Return values are only meaningful when the code that calls functions is well defined. The code is well into undefined behavior, so checking for return values won't be helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable well when I ran that code I got 0 returned, then I used `CommDlgExtendedError`, and that told me 0x3002, INVALIDNAME

Comment: Anyway, according to the first sentence in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamew), this function is more or less deprecated.

Comment: "does that mean this functionality just no longer works in Windows 10?" certainly not, tens or hundreds of thousands apps still use this function.

Answer (score 6):

You pass a pointer to an uninitialized array:

```
wchar_t Filename[500];
...
ofn.lpstrFile    = Filename;
```

According to [the documentation for `lpstrFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamew):

> [...] used to initialize the File Name edit control

If you don't want a default filename, simply pass an empty string:

```
wchar_t Filename[500] = "";
...
ofn.lpstrFile    = Filename;
```

Also, you should pass the correct length of the buffer so it doesn't overflow when many files are selected:

```
ofn.nMaxFile     = sizeof(Filename)/sizeof(Filename[0]);
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` is a way of calculating the size of C array. It's the number of elements (wchars here), not bytes.

Comment: My bad, I didn't scroll far enough to see the division. I would still recommend using `_countof()` or `std::size()` instead, keep the code clean

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I have tried adding an empty string as the default filename. It has not fixed the issue. While passing the correct length of the buffer is important, I don't think it has anything to do with this problem as the buffer doesn't even get used until you actually select a file. This program crashes before you can even do that.

Comment: @kokinosjunkpile the rest of the code is fine, so if the problem doesn't go away with the changes suggested, then the culprit is most likely a malfunctioning shell extension installed on your machine.  Try disabling the `OFN_EXPLORER` functionality to see if the problem goes away. Or, try not using such an old/deprecated API in the first place, see if the newer `IFileDialog` API works instead.